# Nested callback to main thread from a dispatch queue not working?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

```
__block int x = 5;
dispatch_queue_t abe = dispatch_queue_create([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"abe'sQueue.%@", self] UTF8String], NULL);
dispatch_sync(abe, ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", [self returnSomething]);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        x = 20;
    });
});

NSLog(@"%d", x);
```

The above always results in 5 being the logged value of 'x', even though the nested callback to the main thread changes the value asynchronously. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are dispatching asynchronously to the main queue.  That block is enqueued and the dispatch_async() returns immediately.   Assuming the rest of the code is running on the main thread, then the asynchronously enqueued block won't be run until the next pass through the main event loop, which won't happen until after all of your code above executes.

For setting a scalar variable in that fashion, there is no reason to dispatch_async() to the main thread.   Just set the variable directly (as the main thread is blocked on the dispatch_sync().

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. A quick followup question: If there are multiple queues of this kind - and taking from the iOS dev library that they can run concurrently - will I still need to include the nested 'dispatch_async' function since for sure some queues will run on different threads?

Comment: For scalars?  No need beyond dealing with "normal" concurrency issues.  For non-scalars or for taking action that may cause a UI update?  Yeah -- you'll likely need to dispatch back to the main queue.  Depends on situation.   And, of course, any time you do anything asynchronously, you have to deal with how to coordinate notifications of when the value changes.